# Downloading Google Analytics Data By Client_id

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, mean-stack, google-analytics-api

I'm allowing users of my site to download their google analytics data at their free will for transparency sake and I don't want to deal with CCPA requests for data myself.

I'm using Node.js as my backend and was wondering if it's possible to download google analytics by client_id. I'm using a service account for my google console access.

If there's some documented api endpoint that I'm not seeing that would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you have, it came in for that purpose

> The User Activity API allows a Google Analytics property owner to
>   retrieve all analytics measurement data associated with a single user.
>   Specifically, the API retrieves all of the measurement data associated
>   with a particular User ID or Client ID.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting